# wordpress Plugin to Display subpages when we are on a subpage

Tags: wordpress

am trying to get the subpages list when am on a subpage too, like below

```
mainpage1
 subpage1
 subpage2
 subpage3
```

When i click on subpage1, it should display all the subpages with its parent like below:

```
mainpage1
 subpage1
 subpage2
 subpage3
```

I need a Plugin to do this, any help would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the menu structure in plugin with the simple code like what you want, here is the code, hope its helps you

code :

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_custom_menu_page' );

function my_custom_menu_page(){

//Main Menu

add_menu_page( 'Main Menu', 'Main Menu', 'manage_options', 'main-menu', 'main_menu_callback','' );

//Sub Menu

add_submenu_page( 'mian-menu', 'Sub Menu', 'Sub Menu', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu', 'sub_menu_callback' );

}

Feel my answer is good for you, please mark it as Solution, so other can take the benefits of it.